# How to know position of user press on the element?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm making some sort of game which an object is inside a grid. I want the user be able to press and move his finger horizontally or vertically and the object moves according to his finger's move, horizontally or vertically.

I tried using:

```
<Grid MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">
    <Image Source="..." Width="50" Height="50"/>
</Grid>
```

but it seems those events are useless.

**How can I know position of user's finger on an element (`Grid`) continuously?** thanks

Comment: You might want to look into `Thumb`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the Manipulation events,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You shall use a canvas as the parent control for dragging an object, and use MouseDragElementBehavior for dragging.
Somtehing like this would help

```
MouseDragElementBehavior dragBehavior1 = new MouseDragElementBehavior();
                    dragBehavior1.Attach(object to be dragged);
 dragBehavior1.ConstrainToParentBounds = true; //for restricting the object's movement outside the canvas.
BehaviorCollection BehaviorColl1 = Interaction.GetBehaviors(object to be dragged);
BehaviorColl1.Add(dragBehavior1);
```